# add axis behind stacked column

Tags: highcharts

I have here https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/6/ an area and a stacked bar chart But I need to achieve something like : adding another series:column behind this actual but not stacked, starting from jan. 2010 and  end dec. 2010 with a certain position in y axis, my need is quiet simple, but I don't know how achieve, I think I need another X axis ? 
Actually I have:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    ordinal: false
  },
```

Maybe I need add array to this or so?

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with a second axis, but it's not necessary.

If you add your new data series, with some additional parameters to control the size and spacing, it can all use the same x axis.

**Example:**

```
{
  "name": 'Summary',
  type: 'column',
  grouping: false, <-- make sure they don't group with the other series
  stacking: false, <-- make sure they don't stack on the other series
  color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
  pointRange: 86400000 * 365, , <-- 1 year; set to desired time frame
  pointInterval: 86400000 * 365, <-- 1 year; set to desired time frame
  pointPadding: 0.01,
  groupPadding: 0,
  data: [10000, 15000, 9000, 13000]
}
```

**Updated fiddle:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ezhp5a4j/15/

**Output:**

[image]

**EDIT for comment:**

To add a second axis, you change the `xAxis` object to an array of objects, like this:

```
xAxis: [{
  type: 'datetime',
  ordinal: false
},{
  linkedTo: 0,
  type: 'datetime',
  ordinal: false
}]
```

If they are going to have different scales, I am not sure that it makes any sense to plot them together, but in that case, you would remove the `linkedTo: 0`

Then, in your data, you need to specify which data series are plotted on the second axis, by adding `xAxis: 1` to the series options (you don't need to specify `xAxis: 0` for the other series, as `0` is the default.

Since you have specified a `pointStart` in your `plotOptions`, if the series plotted on the second axis will have a different scale, you will need to specify a separate `pointStart` in that series options.

Update example fiddle:

- https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ezhp5a4j/16/

Comment: yes  this is awesome and neirly what I need,  how can I have the same thinkg with another axis ? because I haven different starting and end date at Y position. Iis it possible from my jsfiddle ? I don't know how create in a proper way another axis, thanks

Comment: See updated answer and fiddle. But I would strongly suggest **not** using two axes for this arrangement - if you have different starting and end points, use the earliest start point, and the latest end point, so that the data is plotted in a way that makes sense together.

Comment: awesome but you said to use start point and end point what you mean ? in your example you use an interval but I have different column size do you mean it's preferable to add different object like this 

`{
    "name": 'Summary',
    type: 'column',
    grouping: false,
    stacking: false,
    color: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)',
    pointRange: 86400000 * 365,
    pointInterval: 86400000 * 365,
    pointPadding: 0.01,
    groupPadding: 0,
    data: [10000, 15000, 9000, 13000]
  }`

 you mean add multiple object like this? I will add TAGS after so that's because I think use new axis

Comment: what I meant was that if you're plotting date data together like this, it's preferable to use the same axis, so that dates are properly aligned together, and not misleading. If you're comparing previous year, or something, that might make more sense though.

Comment: ok I understand it's better not use another axis so you advice me using something like this ? https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/18/ because I can't specify pointEnd ? I need one column with from-to date and another one with different date from-to, I think I'm wrong because not works (ps to understand better I only have 10 items instead of my old LONG jsonData series) thanks to you help but need

Comment: I think the problem there is the `pointRange` value - this property specifies how many axis units the point should cover. With a `datetime` axis type, the units are milliseconds, so by setting it to a date of `Date.UTC(2010, 0, 2)`, you are telling the chart to make the column be 1,262,408,400,000 ms, or **40 years** in width **:)**  In my example, I set the `pointRange` to 1 year ( `pointRange: 86400000 * 365` )

Comment: I did what you said and https://jsfiddle.net/ezhp5a4j/20/ my column aren't in correct position the first must begin 1 until 2 and seconds from 5 until 10 (january 2010) but it isn't is it normal ?

Comment: Your requirements keep getting more confusing :) The `pointRange` is the range *around* the point - so, if your data point is on January 5th, the 5 day range is centered around that date. I think you may be trying to jam too much information into one chart, and you're going to end up with a chart that is bordering on useless because it's trying to do too much.  FWIW

Comment: Ah ok pointRange is around my point lol, I understand what you said but do you mean I cant set start and End date? To my column? I need one column start 1 to 3january and another one start 5to 10 january that's all, thanks to your help really appreciate

Comment: Correct - you cannot specify a start and end date for a data point.

Comment: Thats because I say with another axis it's possible!? Hiw achieve, donno

Comment: Another axis won't change that. A different approach would be to use an `area` series, with the `step` property, possibly, instead of columns. That adds complexity to your data setup though.

Comment: Updated example using an area series:  https://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/ezhp5a4j/21/

Comment: second it! this seems good I'm open to have area :D this is great idea!

Comment: your jsfiddle seems great but does this area have start and end point ? maybe with another x axis because actually like your jsfiddle I need a lot of data point if  my area is about 1year ... problem

Comment: The data points are what makes the start and end point, regardless of how many axes you have. Another axis **won't change any of the things we're discussing**.

Comment: certainly there is a big logic but I don't understand why there is not endPoint , it confusing me but certainly i'm wrong to thing to add endPoint...anyway... very big thanks

Comment: the `pointStart` and `pointInterval` exist so that you can specify your data without needing to provide the dates in each data point, for data that represents equally spaced intervals (a data point each day, or each hour, or whatever). There is no `pointEnd` because it's not needed - chart knows when to start them, how often to plot them, and they end where they end.  If supplying the `x` values directly in the data, `pointStart` and `pointInterval` should not be used, and, once again, the *end point is determined by the data itself*. The concept of an `endPoint` is something to let go of :)

Comment: If you want to specify where the axis starts and ends, regardless of where the data starts and ends, just use the axis `min` and `max` properties: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max